# Is there any alternative to the Mac OS X dashboard?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, macosx

As the title states, does anyone know of a dashboard alternative for Ubuntu? This is useful feature in Mac OS X, middle-clicking on the mouse brings up a customizable page where you can put anything from weather and stock reports to games. Is there any equivilent for this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiz widget layer + screenlets works like this. You can also install or Plasma if you want even more fancy stuff.

You can enable the widget layer in CCSM. (More detail will be added to this answer when I have some more time).

---

- Run: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager screenlets screenlets-pack-all`
- Open this and go the widget layer plugin:
- Widget Layer options:
  [image: Widget Layer]
- Run the screenlets app: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>+`screenlets`
- Set the screenlets options so that they show on the widget layer by default:
  [image: screenlets]
  (then)
  [image: options]

Comment: Thank you, and please do add more detail as I don't know what your'e talking about. :) I do play with compost some, but not enough to know what you mean.

Comment: @William: did something quick :) - I'll polish it later.

Answer (score 2):

Cairo-Dock seems to be close to what you're asking for. You can install it simply by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is cario-dock? I don't need a dock, I have rocky for that.

Comment: I kind of misunderstood what you were asking I guess. It sounds more like you're asking for a customizable widget lens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you have in mind, but [Cairo Dock](http://glx-dock.org) allows for bringing up customizable pages where you can put things like weather reports.  So I'll second the previous recommendation of Cairo Dock.

You can have a look at some screenshots demonstrating what you can do with Cairo Dock using the following link:
http://glx-dock.org/mc_album.php?a=3

Comment: Well, it seems that Cairo-dock might suit my needs, but Roland suggested an application for the sole purpose of a widget layer that I think would do the job better, being a one trick pony.

Answer (score 0):

I think CONKY is the best dock around, it is officially supported and you can download it by running "sudo apt-get install conky" in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want a dock.